# CSS link layout issue Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css

I am building a new website. The HTML and CSS is verified but I have trouble displaying the correct layout for IE7. You can view a screenshot of the problem here:

[image]

How do I prevent IE7 from putting the extra space between the breadcrumbs links?

The links should be like this:

[image]

Comment: no idea. what are the html and css that make up the bread crumbs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your CSS as it doesn't display correctly in FF either. In `ie.css`, modify the following classes like this:

```
#breadcrumbs li a{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/bread-separator.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}

#breadcrumbs li.sort a{
    background-image: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5d3d2;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

I could on test these in FF through FireBug, but it should work on IE as well. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I did the changes you told me to but i cannot see any difference in ie7. Send me a screenshot of what you saw in firefox before

Comment: It looked like [this](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/3905/ssbeforemod.png). Now it looks like it should, I actually had to revert these changes back to get the screen shot.